# Bind DNS server: redirect only subdomain

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

We've some domain (mydom.tld) and in the svn subdomain we have the Subversion server.

This server resides in the main office, and must be accessed inside this office as well as outside it.

So, now we have to edit the /etc/hosts file each time we enter the office, and re-edit when we go outside to make it work.

I've configured the DNS server (bind9 under Ubuntu) so we can use it as I described above, but the problem is that it manages the whole mydom.tld domain, when I only want it to manage the subdomain.

Desired behavior:

- mydom.tld -> no answer
- asdf.mydom.tld -> no answer
- svn.mydom.tld -> 192.168.1.X

Can someone give a solution based on the file /etc/bind/named.conf.local and similar ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [view](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/index.html#view) feature of bind with this `named.conf` :

```
view "internal" {
 match-clients { 192.168.1.0/24; }; // your network
  recursion yes;
  // required zone for recursive queries
  zone "." {
   type hint;
   file "root.servers";
  };
  zone "sub.mydom.tld" {
   type master;
   // private zone file including local hosts
   file "view/master.sub.mydom.tld.internal";
  };
  // required local host domain
  zone "localhost" in{
   type master;
   file "master.localhost";
   allow-update{none;};
  };
  // localhost reverse map
  zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" in{
   type master;
   file "localhost.rev";
   allow-update{none;};
  };
}; // end view

// external hosts view
view "external" {
 match-clients {"any"; }; // all other hosts
  // recursion not supported
  recursion no;
 zone "mydom.tld" {
   type master;
     // only public hosts
   file "view/master.example.com.external";
  };
}; // end view
```

Comment: Ok, so I've done what you've proposed, and my view/master.sub.mydom.tld.internal file is this: [link](http://pastebin.com/xA6DWcLg), but doesn't work at all...

Answer (score 0):

Getting no answer for `mydom.tld` is easy.  I suspect what you want is for it to give the *correct* answer.

i.e.

Outside the office you get this:

- mydom.tld -> 10.0.0.1
- asdf.mydom.tld -> NXDOMAIN
- svn.mydom.tld -> 10.0.0.2

Inside, you get this:

- mydom.tld -> 10.0.0.1
- asdf.mydom.tld -> NXDOMAIN
- svn.mydom.tld -> 192.168.1.1

The easiest way I can see is to copy your production Bind config down to your Office Bind server and edit just that one entry.  You could set this up in a daily cron job so that any changes to production are reflected in the office 24 hours later.  (Details of this are up to you - hourly cron job, SVN checkout, etc.)

If you aren't running Bind in production or you are using a third-party service such as your registrar's DNS service, then you could use a zone transfer instead.  (`AXFR`)

Comment: No, really I want to get no answer, because any DNS server (ie Google) will give a correct DNS answer. mydom.tld is a domain managed by my registrar, and I only want to manage the svn subdomain.

Comment: If your clients ask your office DNS server for `mydom.tld` and it gives them *no* answer, the clients will wait for a timeout period before going off to ask public DNS.  This will cause delays whenever trying to use your domain from within your office.  Giving an authoritative `NXDOMAIN` answer (which is probably what it's doing now.) means that the clients won't ever go off to public DNS and will assume that `mydom.tld` has no A records.  Serving the correct answer from your office DNS is quick and works.

Comment: Hmmm... I get your point, any resource on how to configure AXFR??